# Hibernate 5: SaveOrUpdateEventListener is not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a mapped supper class, which is extended by all entities.

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseEntity implements SaveOrUpdateEventListener {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp createdOn;

    @Column(name = "last_update", nullable = false)
    @Version
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;

    public BaseEntity() { }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedOn() {
        return this.createdOn;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setCreatedOn(Timestamp createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setLastUpdate(Timestamp lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        this.createdOn = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) throws HibernateException {
        this.createdOn = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

I have an Opportunity entity that extends BaseEntity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OPPORTUNITY")
public class Opportunity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "OPPORTUNITY_TAGS")
    private Set<String> tags;

    public Opportunity() {
        this.tags = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Set<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public void addTag(String tag) {
        this.tags.add(tag);
    }
}
```

But when I don't want to set creation time and updation time from client side, I want it to be auto generated by Server. But I am getting following runtime exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.inbhiwadi.model.Opportunity.createdOn
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:92)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:69)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:668)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:660)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:655)
at com.inbhiwadi.dao.EntityDao.create(EntityDao.java:25)
at com.inbhiwadi.dao.OpportunityDaoTest.create(OpportunityDaoTest.java:28)
at com.inbhiwadi.dao.OpportunityDaoTest.read(OpportunityDaoTest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

No idea where things are going wrong. Apparently, none of PrePersist and SaveOrUpdateListener is working.

Comment: please annotate `@PreUpdate` for the method `onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)` and also you need to set the `lastUpdate` field for insert / update as it is not nullable

Comment: @diufanman it is not working. Not even compiling.

Comment: Can you show me the code how you update your object? Use hibernate session or entitymanager?